# how to get a list of the open windows within an application

Tags: python, pywin32, pywinauto, win32gui

Trying to obtain a list of open window(s) but within an application.

Using the code below shows the top level windows and one of them is the application in question

```
names = []

def winEnumHandler(hwnd, ctx):
    if win32gui.IsWindowVisible(hwnd):
        n = win32gui.GetWindowText(hwnd)
        if n:
            names.append(n)
            print(n)

win32gui.EnumWindows(winEnumHandler, None)

print(names)
```

Within that application there are open windows that are not on this list and seem to be part of the main window. 
Is there any way to be more granular and obtain list of open window(s) within specified application?

Comment: It worked for me. See below.

Comment: *IDLE Shell 3.12.1*
6b.py - C:\Users\Supra\Documents\python3_dummy\tmp_dummy\temp-Dummy\6b.py (3.12.1)
python - how to get a list of the open windows within an application - Stack Overflow - DuckDuckGo
Command Prompt
Program Manager
['*IDLE Shell 3.12.1*', '6b.py - C:\\Users\\Supra\\Documents\\python3_dummy\\tmp_dummy\\temp-Dummy\\6b.py (3.12.1)', 'python - how to get a list of the open windows within an application - Stack Overflow - DuckDuckGo', 'Command Prompt', 'Program Manager']

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.work for me atleast

```
app = application.Application(backend='uia').start("your path")
time.sleep(20)
# Get a list of open windows
windows = app.windows()
# Iterate through the list and print window titles
for window in windows:
    print(window.texts())
```

Answer (score 0):

There are other ways to do this, like with psutil. You can get information about the pids that psutil generates using PyWin32.

Anyway here is a chunk of code using just PyWin32.

```py
import win32gui


def EnumWindowProc(hwnd, windows):
    if win32gui.IsWindowVisible(hwnd):
        def EnumChildWindowProc(hwnd, children):
            if win32gui.IsWindowVisible(hwnd):
                children.append((hwnd, win32gui.GetWindowText(hwnd)))

        children = []
        win32gui.EnumChildWindows(hwnd, EnumChildWindowProc, children)

        windows.append((hwnd, win32gui.GetWindowText(hwnd), children))


windows = []
win32gui.EnumWindows(EnumWindowProc, windows)
for hwnd, title, children in windows:
    print(hwnd, title)
    for child_hwnd, child_title in children:
        print(f'\t{child_hwnd}, {child_title}')
```

Here is another chunk of code using psutil to get the process, which is Notepad.exe and using win32gui, and win32process to get the window for Notepad and all of the visible child windows.

```py
from win32gui import SendMessage, IsWindowVisible, EnumWindows, EnumChildWindows, GetWindowText
from win32process import GetWindowThreadProcessId
from psutil import Process, process_iter

def enumerate_windows(hwnd, pid):
    def enumerate_children(hwnd, pid):
        if pid in GetWindowThreadProcessId(hwnd) and IsWindowVisible(hwnd):
            print(f'\t\t{hwnd} - {GetWindowText(hwnd) + " - "  if GetWindowText(hwnd) else ""}{GetWindowThreadProcessId(hwnd)}')

    if pid in GetWindowThreadProcessId(hwnd) and IsWindowVisible(hwnd):
        print(f'\t{hwnd} - {GetWindowText(hwnd)} - {GetWindowThreadProcessId(hwnd)}')
        EnumChildWindows(hwnd, enumerate_children, pid)
        print()


for process in process_iter():
    if process.name() == 'Notepad.exe':
        print(f'{process.pid} - {process.name()}')
        EnumWindows(enumerate_windows, process.pid)
        print()

        for child in process.children():
            print(child.pid, child.name())
```